# How do I get a Rosewill USB wireless adapter RNX-N180UBE working?

Tags: networking

Need a how to install for Rosewill USB wireless adapter RNX-N180UBE.

Dell laptop using Ubuntu 12.04.
Rosewill USB wireless adapter RNX-N180UBE.

`lsusb` shows as: `obda:8172` and `Realtek Corp RTL8191SU`
`lsmod` shows: `r8172u`

Could someone step me thru the install?

Any more info I'll provide.

Comment: If you insert the device and a driver loads in lsmod, I think that's all the installation you need. Didn't the laptop come with a built-in wireless card? Is it not working? Is the wireless switch set to enable wireless: rfkill list all. When you click the Network Manager icon, does it see networks? I believe the driver is actually r8712u.

Answer (score 1):

Found install documentation here:

- http://www.rosewill.com/rosewill-rnx-ac1200ube2-11ac-wireless-usb-ac1200-wi-fi-adapter.html#product_tabs_Downloads

Download and unzip the file.
Includes readme and install.sh.
Will work on this now.
Will not always be using the USB adapter.